# is it possible to change sqllite settings using adb?

Tags: android, adb

I want to change the screen timeout to 30 mins using adb. i can run monkeyrunner too, but that will take time. Is there a way to change the settings in SQL lite db using adb? I'm using this to automate a few things.
Same thing for stay awake in USB debugging node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**if it's emulator or your devices is rooted**, you can modify the setting sqlite database.

how:
  cd to the setting application database folder, and run `sqlite3 databasename.db`, then you can modify the database as you like

Comment: yupps it is rooted!! tried this: 
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "update system set value='18000000' where name='screen_off_timeout';"
but it did not work... where am i wrong? Do I have to restart the device after this??

Comment: yes, suggestion restart the device, and when you use `update system set value='18000000' where name='screen_off_timeout'`, you need check the data column has be changed.

Comment: data column got changed but the screen timed out within a min. any idea of avoiding a restart?

Answer (score 7):

Below command to change screen time out value

```
adb shell settings put system screen_off_timeout 60000
```

Comment: Is 60000 equal to 30 minutes? I suspect not as from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330518/prevent-screen-sleeping