# Prevent screen sleeping

Tags: android, adb

Android v4.2.2. I'm trying to stop the screen from going to sleep.  I've tried a few things like changing the relevant settings in the db:

```
adb shell "sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db  \"update system set value='-1' where name='screen_off_timeout'\";"
```

But that didn't work - screen just went to sleep almost immediately.  If I go to the settings app there isn't an option to disable it.  Instead, it ranges from 15s to 30m.

I have also tried to set the `KEEP_SCREEN_ON` FLAG in the application but that stops working when I switch to a new activity.

Is there anything else I can try.  I was hoping a db setting would do the job.  Here is my system db as it stands.  Perhaps a setting I am missing and can insert?

```
1|volume_music|11
2|volume_ring|5
3|volume_system|7
4|volume_voice|4
5|volume_alarm|6
6|volume_notification|5
7|volume_bluetooth_sco|7
8|mode_ringer_streams_affected|174
9|mute_streams_affected|46
10|vibrate_when_ringing|0
11|dim_screen|0
13|dtmf_tone_type|0
14|hearing_aid|0
15|tty_mode|0
16|screen_brightness|102
17|screen_brightness_mode|0
18|window_animation_scale|1.0
19|transition_animation_scale|1.0
20|accelerometer_rotation|1
21|haptic_feedback_enabled|1
22|notification_light_pulse|1
23|dtmf_tone|1
24|sound_effects_enabled|1
26|lockscreen_sounds_enabled|1
27|pointer_speed|0
28|next_alarm_formatted|
29|alarm_alert|content://media/internal/audio/media/5
30|notification_sound|content://media/internal/audio/media/7
31|ringtone|content://media/internal/audio/media/9
32|volume_music_headset|10
33|volume_music_last_audible_headset|10
34|volume_music_headphone|10
35|volume_music_last_audible_headphone|10
36|time_12_24|24
37|date_format|dd-MM-yyyy
39|stay_on_while_plugged_in|1
45|screen_off_timeout|-1
```

Answer (score 25):

Your setting db contains default time out set by the system which is probably low so the device went to sleep immediately due to low timeout value. You can issue adb shell command to increase screen timeout.

```
adb shell settings put system screen_off_timeout 60000
```

Note: 60000 = 1 minute

You can also update setting db with the desired timeout and then push db back to device but it requires root. Above command does not require device to be rooted.

Comment: `adb shell settings get system screen_off_timeout` to get the timeout value in the device

Comment: Thanks @parerariddle for additional info.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to `Activity` , There is no impact from `DB`. Just add `android:keepScreenOn="true"` to the `layout` in your `xml`

Comment: Presumably I'll have to add this to every activity.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
 wl.acquire();
```

For more go through this link http://thiranjith.com/2012/02/22/android-prevent-screen-timeout/

Comment: To Use This, You need to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> in your manifest file.